# Bulk update in postgreSQL using unnest

Tags: postgresql, bulkupdate

I am trying to do bulk update:

```
> update ti_table set enabled=T.enabled 
    from (select * from 
         unnest(array['2001622', '2001624', '2007903']) as id,
         unnest(array[15,14,8]) as ver,
         unnest(array['type1', 'type1', 'type1']) as type,
         unnest(array[false, true, true]) as enabled) T 
    where ti_table.id=T.id AND ti_table.ver=T.ver AND ti_table.type=T.type;
```

However, when I read back:

```
> select id, ver, type, enabled from ti_table where id in ('2001622', '2001624', '2007903');
```

I see:

```
   id    | ver | type  | enabled 
---------+-----+-------+---------
 2001622 |  15 | type1 | f
 2001624 |  14 | type1 | f
 2007903 |   8 | type1 | f
```

In the last two rows **enabled** is `false` while I expected it to be `true`

Why is this happening and how would I do it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you are updating `ti_table` and reading back `ti_rules`.

Comment: it appears that the subquery is returning 81 results (3*3*3*4)... apparently each unnest returns a set for each value...

Comment: @MatheusOl I fixed that it is a typo. The problem is that the inner select does a cartesian product rather than creating a single row for each set of values with the same index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `unnest` 3 times on `FROM` clause, that means you are doing a `CROSS JOIN` (cartesian product) of the 3.

If you are on PostgreSQL 9.4 or higher, you can simple do one call of `unnest` giving each array as input:

```
select * from 
         unnest(
            array['2001622', '2001624', '2007903'],
             array[15,14,8],
             array['type1', 'type1', 'type1'],
             array[false, true, true]
        ) as u(id, ver, type, enabled)
```

Another option, for any version, is to add the call to `unnest` in `SELECT` instead of `FROM`:

```
select
   unnest(array['2001622', '2001624', '2007903']) as id,
   unnest(array[15,14,8]) as ver,
   unnest(array['type1', 'type1', 'type1']) as type,
   unnest(array[false, true, true]) as enabled
```

In both cases, but specially on the last one, you must be sure each array have the exact same number of elements. If it doesn't on the first method each missing row will be filled as NULL, but the second one it will return as many rows as the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the number of rows returned by each, what you probably do not want. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM unnest(array[1,2,3,4], array['a','b','c','d','e','f']);
 unnest | unnest 
--------+--------
      1 | a
      2 | b
      3 | c
      4 | d
 [null] | e
 [null] | f
(6 rows)

SELECT unnest(array[1,2,3,4]), unnest(array['a','b','c','d','e','f']);
 unnest | unnest 
--------+--------
      1 | a
      2 | b
      3 | c
      4 | d
      1 | e
      2 | f
      3 | a
      4 | b
      1 | c
      2 | d
      3 | e
      4 | f
(12 rows)
```

Check the documentation on [table functions calls](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it using PostgreSQL `VALUES`:

```
UPDATE ti_table ti
SET enabled = data.enabled
FROM (
  VALUES
    ('2001622', 15, 'type1', false),
    ('2001624', 14, 'type1', true),
    ('2007903', 8, 'type1', true)
) AS data(id, ver, type, enabled)
WHERE ti.id = data.id
AND ti.ver = t.ver
AND ti.type = data.type;
```

It's easier to read, because values are grouped together by rows.

Comment: I think the point of using `unnest()` is so that it can be injected via a parameter easier